# Setting-up multiple mercurial users under the same user account

Tags: mercurial

I have the following scenario. I am using mercurial on the projects that I am working for at my company, thus I created my .hgrc file with the following settings:

```
#first username: work repo
username = pablo <pablo@work.com>
```

I would like to, in addition to that, be able to commit to my private repository, with my private repository from the same computer/account. Would it be possible to have another username? For example:

```
#second username, used for private repo
username = pablo <pablo@funmail.com>
```

If so, how would I commit choose which account is committing to a repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Mercurial working directory has a `.hg/hgrc` file, and those settings take precedence over the settings in your `$HOME/.hgrc` file or the `/etc/hgrc` file.

Comment: So, if I have a hgrc per repository, I could safely delete my $HOME/.hgrc?

Comment: You could, but usually you have some settings that you want to use for all your repositories. If you want everything at system default, you won't need any .hgrc files (IIRC, mercurial defaults to your unix username when none is defined explicitly).